# Crashlytics not recording crashes for archived builds

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to integrate Crashlytics in my project. I have successfully added Crashlytics using Cocoapods

[image: Pod]

I have added Fabric run and upload symbols script in Build Phases.

[image: Fabric Run]

[image: Upload Symbols]

Order of Run scripts are UploadSymbols > Fabric run

Also set Debug information format to DWARF with dSYM File

[image: Debug Information format]

Enable Bitcode is set to YES

Added `FirebaseApp.configure()` in `AppDelegate.swift` 
and added `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` in code to force a crash.

I can see crash logs in Firebase-Crashlytics console when I run in debug mode > stop > launch app again > force crash.

But when I archive and upload to App Center (Enterprise Build), crashes are not showing in Firebase console.

dSYM required error showing. I can see the version in both cases.

Not sure if I am missing anything.

Enterprise build is created using Fastlane.

IDE: Xcode 11.3.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [IMPORTANT](https://get.fabric.io/) Fabric shutdown extended to May 4, 2020 due to COVID-19

Comment: so should I use fiebase crashlytics pod instead of Fabric and Crashlytics pod..??

Comment: Both Fabric and Firebase Crashlytics are the [same](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started). You can try some other service like [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms/) which is available for now.

Comment: Client wants Crashlytics. decision is not up on me. :)

Comment: Do you have the upload symbols line in your fastfile? https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_symbols_to_crashlytics/

Comment: @OlegKodysh I didn't have. once I added fastlane, working fine. still not sure why the script in the question not working